# Is there an R function for refreshing a datafile or dataframe to pick up recently updated data automatically?

Tags: r, refresh, reactive-programming, real-time-updates

I have a csv file where data is getting generated for every 15 mins. I need R programming to use reactivefilereader function to identify latest data feed and update automatically.

But what is the problem with the code below ?

```
library(readr)
housing <- read_csv("C:/Users/KTPani/Desktop/CD/housing.csv")
```

```
function(input, output, session) {
  housing <- reactiveFileReader(9000, session, 'housing.csv', read.csv)

  output$data <- renderTable({
    housing()})}

View(housing)
```